# Apache Flink: What is the difference of groupBy and partitioning in the DataSet API?

Tags: apache-flink

There are various partitioning function in Flink's Dataset API, such as `partitionByHash` and `partitionByRange`.

I would like to understand what is partitioning at the first place and what is the difference between `groupBy` and partitioning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Partitioning is a more low-level operation than `groupBy` and does not apply a function on the data. It rather defines how data is distributed across parallel task instances. Data can be partitioned with different methods such as hash partitioning or range partitioning.

`groupBy` is not an operation by itself. It always needs a function that is applied on the grouped `DataSet` such as `reduce`, `groupReduce`, or `groupCombine`. The `groupBy` API defines how records are grouped before they are given into the respective function. Grouping of records happens in two steps.

1. All records with the same grouping key must be moved to the same task instance. This is done by partitioning the data. Since there are usually more distinct grouping keys than task instances, a task instance must handle records with distinct grouping keys.
2. All records in the same task instance must be grouped on the key. This is usually done by sorting the data.

So, the first step of `groupBy` is partitioning.

Comment: I have few question based on your answer.  
(1)By task instance, you mean separate task manager instance.
(2)Since records need to be partitioned before grouping, there is a chance that records with same key can be on different task instances.
(3)Since the first step of `groupBy` is  partition, what is  the default partitioning technique followed when we apply `groupBy` transformation

Comment: (1) Task instance is not the same as TaskManager instance. A TaskManager can execute one instance of each task (or operator) per slot. (2) No, after partitioning all records with the same key will be processed by the same task instance. (3) by default, `groupBy()` uses hash partitioning.

Comment: #2 What if the size of data of a particular a key is larger than the memory of the task slot ?

Comment: Flink features an external sort algorithm. Batches of records are sorted in memory. The sorted batches are spilled to disk and later read by a merge-sort.

Comment: @FabianHueske Does the DataStream API spill to disk too?

Comment: It depends on the configured state backend whether a worker writes to disk. The RocksDB state backend writes to disk, the FS state backend does not.

Comment: @FabianHueske Alright, but the DataSet API spills to disk regardless of the backend configured?

Comment: No. DataSet API doesn't use state backend but it's operators manage memory themselves. If data fits into memory, no data is spilled.

Comment: @FabianHueske Thank you. I think from 1.12 Flink has recommended users to use a unified DataStream API. I hope this makes things simple.